# Saving tomorrows date into variable

Tags: bash, date, awk, syntax

I want to get a tomorrow`s date into variable, i can get it without problem and it prints correctly but when i want to save it into variable it seems empty, i tried different approaches, even using *awk* but nothing seems to work. Also tried to exchange `$()` for  back quote but with no succes

`day=$(date -d "1 day"| awk '{ $2}')`

`day=$(date '+%d' -d "1 day" )`

as long as i use those without trying to assign to variable everything works but after assigning - variable is empty

Comment: `day=$(date '+%d' -d "1 day" ); echo $day` is working just fine.

Comment: @WilliamMartens , https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285777/10910692

Comment: using another comment just to say Do not take the above comment as offense (and neither should anyone else) and I completely agree with the link, :)
+1

Comment: I don't disagree with you @WilliamMartens and I have question the same thing about the _"downvote and run"_ before. Overtime I began to think "that's just how it is..".

Comment: @FaNo_FN Oh okay,  really - The reply was just to clarify-no-offense; But thanks!
Have a great continuing (corona free) day!

Answer (score 3):

The line with `awk` is missing `print` (and the number depends on the locale, I used 3 which works for `C`).

```
day=$(date -d '1 day' | awk '{print $3}')
echo $day
```

The other line should work.

You can also use `tomorrow` directly to make it more readable:

```
day=$(date +%d -d tomorrow )
echo $day
```

Comment: I try to remember to use `%-d` -- if there is intention to use the date in arithmetic, the shell won't trip over invalid octal number 08 and 09

Answer (score 0):

The raw "date" command returns a sequence of strings.

```
date --date "now 1 day" returns Tue Jun 22 12:46:21 EDT 2021
```

Therefore, in order to store the result into a variable, the right hand side must be quoted.

```
tomorrow="$(date --date 'now 1 day')"
```

Note that I switched the inner quotes to single quotes.

Comment: While using quotes doesn't hurt (and I'd recommend you always do it until you **need** to not do it), it won't fix the OPs problem since field splitting doesn't happen on a simple assignment. Try `x=$(echo 'foo    bar'); echo "$x"` with multiple blanks between `foo` and `bar`. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for more info.